# How to fix the white space in between the title and scroll down menu

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner so this probably sounds like a simple question. I was just wondering how to make a background for both my title and my scroll down menu. Currently, each have the same background but there is a white space in between the title and the menu as they are different elements. How can I also have the background in the white space? [heres an image to help you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk5y1.png)

Comment: show the code ...make a fiddle on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Could you please post the code including the html and css so we can try and help you out!

Comment: provide some css and html elements which are in the image

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using 'paragraph' tag for your header design. By default paragraph tag have default margin values. Im guessing, if you remove margins in css, your can solve this issue.

```
p.header{
    margin:0; // remove or override default margin values
 }
```

[[Here is the sample of your design]](https://jsfiddle.net/ManikandanMaduraI/p1m4n03n/)

Or still there, please post your code.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap both the thins in a `<section>` or `<div>` tag and assign the `background image` to it. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

By defining different id or class for each section you can easily put the background color.

Let me know this is better for you.